# jQuery $.post isn't working

Tags: jquery, forms, serialization, post

I just started using jQuery, but i can't get it working.

On the index.php page I want a search form that posts to `search.php`. Following next, I want that the HTML of `search.php` (which will only be a table with the results), is inserted into the 'results' `div` in the `index.php`.

This is the code I'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  /* attach a submit handler to the form */
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("Ok - 1");
    $("#zoeken").submit(function (event) {
        alert("Ok - 2");
        event.preventDefault();
        $.post("https://nodots.nl/labs/dd/search.php", $("#zoeken").serialize() {
            alert("Ok - 3");
            success: function (html) {
                $("#result").empty().html(html);
                alert("Ok - 4");
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

The alerts are for debugging, but none of them shows up. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You'll get much better information if you use the browser's developer tools for debugging. It would tell you that you have `SyntaxError`s. And `console.log()` is just so much nicer than `alert()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that for $.post, the third argument is actually the success function, like so:

```
$.post("URL","ARGUMENTS","SUCCESS FUNCTION");
```

so for your needs:

```
$.post("https://nodots.nl/labs/dd/search.php", $("#zoeken").serialize(), 
    function(html)
    {
        $("#result").empty().html(html);
        alert("Ok - 4");
    }
});
```

**Entire Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("Ok - 1");
    $("#zoeken").submit(function (event) {
        alert("Ok - 2");
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("Ok - 3");
        $.post("https://nodots.nl/labs/dd/search.php", $("#zoeken").serialize(),
            function(html) {
                $("#result").empty().html(html);
                alert("Ok - 4");
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: You can see the result at: http://www.nodots.nl/labs/dd/index.php. As you can see, it still isn't working. Chrome is complaining about a 'unexpected token }', but i cant find the mistake.

Comment: Ok, i did find the mistake, and i get the alert 1 to 4. But it doesn't show the results in the #result div.

Comment: I looked through it, I was about to mention that it seemed like you fixed the syntax issue. I noticed a "XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://nodots.nl/labs/dd/search.php. Origin https://www.nodots.nl is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin." error. You might want to check out the following link to help resolve that : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595515/xmlhttprequest-error-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin Hope this helps :)

Comment: All right! The header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); did the trick. Can you explain me how you found out the error 'XMLhttprequest etc...'?

Comment: Using Chrome I was just checking the console, it alerts any errors that occur on the page (or in jQuery / Javascript). That was the exact message it put out. You can use Firebug in Firefox and IE will often notify you of a script error in the lower left corner :)

Answer (score 5):

Syntax error...

```
 $.post("https://nodots.nl/labs/dd/search.php", $("#zoeken").serialize(){
 alert("Ok - 3"); 
 success: function(html){
 $("#result").empty().html(html);
 alert("Ok - 4");
 }
 });
```

On your first line, it should read instead:

```
$.post("https://nodots.nl/labs/dd/search.php", $("#zoeken").serialize(), function() {
```

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure what you are doing.

The proper format for `$.post()` is:

```
$.post(url, post_items, callback);
```

What you should have is:

```
    $.post("https://nodots.nl/labs/dd/search.php", $(this).serialize(), 
                                                   //this is the form!
        function(html) {
            $("#result").empty().html(html);
            alert("Ok - 4");
        }
    });
```

Comment: I did this now, but the result aren't showing up in the #result div.